# Jquery Timer Plugin - Issue with Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, timer

I am using Matt Schmidt's jQuery Timer plugin

```
/*
*
*  jQuery Timer plugin v0.1
*    Matt Schmidt [http://www.mattptr.net]
*
*  Licensed under the BSD License:
*    http://mattptr.net/license/license.txt
*
*/

jQuery.timer = function (interval, callback) {
    /**
    *
    * timer() provides a cleaner way to handle intervals  
    *
    *  @usage
    * $.timer(interval, callback);
    *
    *
    * @example
    * $.timer(1000, function (timer) {
    *   alert("hello");
    *   timer.stop();
    * });
    * @desc Show an alert box after 1 second and stop
    * 
    * @example
    * var second = false;
    *  $.timer(1000, function (timer) {
    *    if (!second) {
    *      alert('First time!');
    *      second = true;
    *      timer.reset(3000);
    *    }
    *    else {
    *      alert('Second time');
    *      timer.stop();
    *    }
    *  });
    * @desc Show an alert box after 1 second and show another after 3 seconds
    *
    * 
    */

    var interval = interval || 100;

    if (!callback)
        return false;

    _timer = function (interval, callback) {
        this.stop = function () {
            clearInterval(self.id);
        };

        this.internalCallback = function () {
            callback(self);
        };

        this.reset = function (val) {
            if (self.id)
                clearInterval(self.id);

            var val = val || 100;
            this.id = setInterval(this.internalCallback, val);
        };

        this.interval = interval;
        this.id = setInterval(this.internalCallback, this.interval);

        var self = this;
    };

    return new _timer(interval, callback);
};
```

I use it in the following chain:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // Get the requestId
        var requestId = $('#RequestId').val();
        var timerInterval = 10000;
        // On document load create a timer which will poll the controller every second
        $.timer(timerInterval, function (timer) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/CreateFIS/GetRequestStatus",
                    data: { strRequestId: requestId },
                    success:
                        function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                            if (response != null) {
                                switch (response.toString()) {
                                    case 'Pending':
                                        // The request is still currently awaiting processing
                                        $('#InformationSpan').html('The request is currently Pending. Please Wait...');
                                        timer.stop();
                                        timer.reset(timerInterval);
                                        break;
                                    case 'Cancelled':
                                        // The request has been cancelled
                                        $('#InformationSpan').html('The request has been cancelled.');
                                        timer.stop();
                                        break;
                                    case 'Error':
                                        // There was an error with the request
                                        $('#InformationSpan').html('There has been an error generating the request. Please contact the administrator regarding this error.');
                                        break;
                                    case 'In Progress':
                                        // Generation is in progress
                                        $('#InformationSpan').html('The request is currently in progress, and will be with you shortly. Please Wait...');
                                        timer.stop();
                                        timer.reset(timerInterval);
                                        break;
                                    case 'Generated':
                                        // Generation has finished
                                        $('#InformationSpan').html('The request has finished generating.');
                                        timer.stop();
                                        //Todo redirect to viewer
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                        alert(req);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```

My problem is, the ajax call is only actually performed once, where I want it to be perfromed each time the timers interval is hit.
I have tried removing the calls to stop() before the call to reset(), however this makes no difference.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: I dont think this really matters, but here is the method on my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetRequestStatus(string strRequestId)
        {
            Guid requestId;
            bool result = Guid.TryParse(strRequestId, out requestId);
            if(!result)
            {
                // TODO handle error here
                return null;
            }
            FISServiceClient fisServiceClient = new FISServiceClient();
            var status = fisServiceClient.GetFISRequestStatus(requestId);
            if (status == null) return null;
            return Json(status.FISRequestStatusName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interval is set to run every 10 seconds, **not** every second as your comment indicates. I've updated the number of milliseconds to the correct 1,000, and created a jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySHUQ/

Everything seems to work properly (obviously receiving the error alerts every second, since the URL doesn't exist). Perhaps you just weren't waiting long enough?

Comment: Sorry Ben, I set the interval to 10 seconds so I could test. The timer fires fine, however the call to the url is not made each time the timer fires for some reason.

Comment: OK. I don't quite understand what you mean? In the fiddle I posted, I receive a series of alerts every second (as fired in the `error` function for the AJAX call. That would indicate there's nothing wrong with the AJAX call. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Of course you receive the error, you dont have the method locally. When debugging here, I can see the method is executed and a value is returned. The method is not called every time the timer fires.

Comment: I fully understand why I receive the error, that's not in question. My point is, this indicates that the `ajax()` function **is** being called every second. If the method isn't being called when the AJAX function is run, there must be a problem somewhere else.

Your original statement was that the AJAX call was 'only actually performed once', which, as evidenced by the error function, isn't true...

Comment: Thanks Ben, the issue was actually in the service the controller called.

Comment: Glad to help, Mick! I suspected the problem was likely elsewhere.